# I need help with a basic Solve question

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following two conditions:

```
Dc == t0^2
Dp == t1^2
```

The actual formulas I'm trying to solve are more complex, but this is the essence of the relations.  I want an expression for Dp as a function of Dc.  I can solve knowing that I can always divide both sides by the same value and using the resulting equality.

```
Dc/t0^2 == 1
Dp/t1^2 == 1
Dp/t1^2 == Dc/t0^2
Dp == Dc * t1^2/t0^2
```

So now I want to use *Solve* to do the same thing, but when I enter the formula:

```
Solve[Dc == t0^2 && Dp == t1^2, Dp]
```

I get an empty set {} back.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**  Oddly, MMa is able to work out the relation when I solve like this:

```
In[]= Solve[Dc == k t0^2 && Dp == k t1^2, Dp, {k}]
Out[]= {{Dp -> (Dc*t1^2)/t0^2}}
```

Comment: `Solve[Dc == t0^2 && Dp == t1^2, Dp, {Dc}]` or `Solve[Dc == t0^2 && Dp == t1^2, {Dp, Dc}]`? Two equations, two unknowns, I guess.  Or: There is no value of `Dp` that makes the first equation `True`.

Comment: Another alternative, if simplest output is necessary: `Solve[Dc == t0^2 && Dp == t1^2, {Dp, Dc}][[All, {1}]]` or `Solve[Dc == t0^2 && Dp == t1^2, {Dc, Dp}][[All, {2}]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I can work out manually that the solution is Dc * t1^2/t0^2.  Is there something wrong with the manual derivation?  Your solutions don't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: The first 2 equation do not give a relation between Dc and Dp. Only the third one is needed. E.g. Solve[Dp/t1^2 == Dc/t0^2, Dc]

Comment: @DanielHuber - That's the part I don't get.  Isn't MMa able to work out the relation the same way I did manually?  Oddly, it's able to work out the relation when I do this:$$Solve[Dc == k t0^2 && Dp == k t1^2, Dp, {k}]$$

Comment: The solution is actually sort of "phony". Note that  Dc is actually Sqrt[t0] and Dp actually Sqrt[t1] . The solution is then: Dp==Dc  Sqrt[t1]^2 / Sqrt[t0]^2 == Dc Dp / Dc what does not give any new information

Comment: Without the `k` the equations are not coupled and there is no reason to believe that `Dc` and `Dp` have any relation to each other. The presence of `k` in each equation creates the coupling.

Comment: I think any internal symbolic algebra algorithm is likely to cancel `Dc/t0^2` given `Dc == t0^2`. Generally they strive to reduce complexity. When it's not given but `Dc == k*t0^2` is, then they will cancel and leave `k` unless `k` is to be eliminated. -- I've yet to figure out how to find what you seek. For instance, manually I can work out a solution to be `Dc^2 * t1^2/t0^4` and thence to an infinite number of expressions that satisfy the equation. How am I to tell *Mma* to avoid mine and seek the one you want, especially if we don't know ahead of time which is desired?

Comment: @BobHanlon - _The presence of k in each equation creates the coupling_  How come the implicit constant '1' doesn't do the same thing as k?

Comment: An explicit factor of `1` is immediately simplified to an implicit factor of `1`, i.e., it disappears.

Comment: @BobHanlon - I can set $k=1$ and then this term disappears just as easily.  Are the equations no longer connected when $k=1$?  Why does the value of $k$ determine whether the equations are connected or not?

Comment: `k` must be a variable (i.e., no value assigned) not a number. The variable couples the equations and subsequently the `Solve` eliminates the artificially introduced variable.